# Rails collection_select: save null instead of empty string when 'blank' option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code for a select box in a form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :user_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

And it displays the following select options:

[image: select options]

I noticed that when the `blank` option is selected, what actually gets saved in the database is an empty string: `''`

I do not want to save an empty string when the `blank` option is selected.  Instead: I want to save `null`.

I attempted overriding the setter in the rails model but it didn't work:

```
def text_value=(value)
  write_attribute(:name, nil) and return if value.empty?
  super
end
```

How might I do this at the application level?  I am aware that I *could* have a Default Value specified at the Database level, but it seems that this might be better suited at the application level.

Comment: Isn't that just a wrong representation that you are looking at? I mean, an integer field will never be an empty string. It can be either a number or null, right?

Comment: In this circumstance: no.  If the blank option is selected then that would mean that the user has not selected an answer, thus `null`.  Pretend that there is another select option that specifies 'does not apply' or 'no' and which actually saves a blank string value.  Saving it as `null` in the database is just a way for me to say 'oh ok, they did not answer this question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
def text_value=(value)
  if value.empty?
    write_attribute(:name, nil)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for multiple attributes and/or models, there's a gem for that:
https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks