# ActiveRecord + ActiveAdmin, save a empty string instead of null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

When I use the Active Admin form, the empty string values are saved as "" (empty) instead of NULL value.

Is there a parameter I should set in the initializer to save every empty values as NULL in MySQL?

```
form do |f|
    input :label
    input :description, as: :text
    input :country
    input :city
  end
  actions
end
```

This is my migration schema:

```
create_table "projects" do |t|
  t.string "label", limit: "40"
  t.string "country", limit: "2"
  t.string "city", limit: "200"
  t.string "description", limit: 600
end
```

And this is my Gemfile.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0.rc1'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.5', require: true
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.7'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre5'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.2.10'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.1.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3.0'
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing because of this?

Comment: The form saves empty values as "" instead of NULL in the MySQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be the default behaviour of forms. I came accross this gem [nilify_blanks](https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks) which will solve your issue.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I saw the gem but the build flag has an error status. And I thought is was deprecated

Comment: I see that too, but you can try and let me know if it breaks ur code, worth a try if you want it for all models keeping it dry. And I think you might have came accross this solution too if not see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40387633/6548745. It is good for limited attributes.

Comment: so which one worked for you? gem or code from the SO link? @Cornelius

Answer (score 1):

This is a Rails, not an ActiveAdmin issue.

If you can, [don't use null for empty strings](http://joshuapaling.com/blog/2015/05/05/nulls-in-database.html). Using null may be theoretically correct, but in practice I have found working with MySQL simpler and less error prone if all varchar columns are set not null, e.g.:

```
t.string :label, limit: 40, null: false
```

The [nilify_blanks](https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/make-values-nil-if-blank-data-normalization-in-rails) gem is unmaintained since Rails 4. Instead, try the following in your model:

```
def label=(label)
  write_attribute :label, label.present? ? label : nil
end
```

Comment: Yes well that's your opinion however from the PoV of truth maintenance, null is someting entirely different than an empty value or a default. In a lot of cases null signals that the value is not known while an empty value signals that the value is known but empty.

I don't think it will be surprising that I disagree with you here.